# Laravel Eloquent Collection remove item from Collection if exist in array

Tags: laravel, collections

I got a simple problem today. I'm working in a Livewire Component, I have a collection of objects, when I click on an object I want to add it to an array (which works) and then want to remove it from the collection - so that object isn't clickable anymore.
What I have:

```
public function addPartToUsage($partId){
    $partToAdd = Part::where('id', '=', $partId)->first();

    $this->verwendung[] = ['id'=> $partToAdd->id, 'partBezeichnung'=>$partToAdd->id.':'.$partToAdd->zeichnungsnummer.' - '.$partToAdd->artikelbezeichnung];

    $this->partsClient = Part::where('artikelbezeichnung', 'LIKE', '%' . $this->inputsearchpart . '%')
        ->orWhere('zeichnungsnummer', 'LIKE', '%' . $this->inputsearchpart . '%')
        ->orderBy('artikelnummer')
        ->get();



    foreach ($this->verwendung as $item) {

        if($this->partsClient->contains('id', $item['id'])){
          
           $this->partsClient->forget($this->partsClient->where('id', $item['id'])->id);
        }  }  }
```

but it is not working because I dont know the key of the element which contains the matching id.

$this->verwendung is my array which holds the id in $this->verwendung[0]['id'] and
$this->partsClient is my collection which comes from the database.

How can I modify the collection without making it to an array and then check against matching ids and then recollect?
Or better how can I retrieve the matching key of the collection, so that I can use forget() ?
Thanks to all here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking if the id is contained in the collection, you can just filter it with `reject()` directly

```
foreach ($this->verwendung as $item) {
    $this->partsClient->reject(function ($value, $key) use ($item) {
        return $value->id == $item['id'];
    });
}
```

Or simply

```
$verwendungCollection = collect($this->verwendung);

$idsToRemove = $verwendungCollection->pluck('id')->toArray();

$this->partsClient->reject(function ($value, $key) use ($item) {
    return in_array($value->id, $idsToRemove);
});
```

Comment: Hi N69S, I won't work :( - I have implemented both versions in my code but the collection still is filled with all Objects. So I tested this code: I filled up my array with values and created a collection  and tried to filter the collection with reject() - colletion stays the same :(

Comment: ` $this->verwendung[] = ['id' => 4, 'partBezeichnung' => 'bez'];
        $this->verwendung[] = ['id' => 55, 'partBezeichnung' => 'bez2']; $checkarr[] = ['id' => 12, 'partBezeichnung' => 'bez12'];
        $checkarr[] = ['id' => 13, 'partBezeichnung' => 'bez13'];
        $checkarr[] = ['id' => 4, 'partBezeichnung' => 'bez4'];
        $checkColl = collect($checkarr);  foreach ($this->verwendung as $item) {
           $checkColl->reject(function ($value, $key) use ($item) {
               return $value['id'] === $item['id'];
           });

       }
       dd($checkColl);`

Comment: What am I missing?  sorry for the comment code I don't know how to correctly format it in comments

Comment: ok delete my comments please ... I've tested it in tinker and it worked as expected. My fault - I have an error in the component, I dont know where :) but I am a small step closer to the finish :) Thx - N69S